# change weight of edge in igraph network

Tags: r, igraph

I would have thought that the graph algorithm picks up the column weight in edge data frame automatically but it does not as shown in the following code:

```
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("1", "2", "3"), type = c("a", "b", "b"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c("1", "1"), to = c("2", "3"), weight = c(10000, 50))

net <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=FALSE, vertices=nodes)
V(net)$size <- 2
V(net)$color <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "a", "darkblue", "orange")
V(net)$shape <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "a", "circle", "square")
plot(net)
```

Is there a way to use a specifically named column in the edge data frame (e.g. weight) to set the thickness of the depicted edges? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
E(net)$width <- edges$weight
plot(net)
```

Comment: Thanks. That help (almost) - looks like a big blob now. Guess one should normalise by something? Sorry an additional question.

Comment: ok E(net)$width <- edges$weight / max(edges$weight) should work but cannot see much change now ...

Comment: ok E(net)$width <- log(edges$weight) or E(net)$width <- edges$weight / max(edges$weight) * 10 seems to help